# ¿es posible insertar elementos un tipo (objeto) en una lista genérica de otro tipo (objeto) ? C# Herencia

Tags: c#, poo

¡hola gente! bueno, tengo como 5-8 clases pero la principal es CFacultad que contiene métodos para registrar, eliminar, buscar etc.  también está una list<> de tipo CPersona(otra clase que contiene nombre, telefono, direccion, etc) la cual utilizo para llevar todos los registros combinados (cosa de mi profesora) entonces tengo un método en CFacultad que asigna becas internas o externas a los estudiantes, sus clases respectivas son CBecaExt y CBecaInt.

```
 public class CPersona
{
    private string nombre;
    // demas atributos
   Nombre() { get { return nombre; } set { nombre = value; } }
   // tpdas mis clases tiene sus propiedades get; set;
}

public class Alumno : CPersona
{
   private string carnet;
   // demas atrib;
}

public class CFacultad
{
   public List<CPersona> cPersonas = List<CPersona>();

   public void Insertar_Alumno()
   {
     CAlumno cAlumno = new CAlumno();
     cAlumno.Nombre;
     cAlumno.Carnet;
     // agregando valores
     cPersonas.Add(cAlumno); // listo registro alumno
     // esto mismo hago para profesores(CProfesor) en otro método. 
   }
}
```

respecto a CBecaExt sólo tiene 1 miembro, monto (cantidad monetaria).

```
public class CBecaExt : Alumno
{
   private int monto;
}
```

ahora, lo que trato de hacer es que cuando alumno solicite Beca Externa, se le asigne el monto digitado por teclado a mi registro List principal.

```
public class CFacultad
{
   public void Insertar_Alumno()
   // ...
   public void Solicitar_BecaExt()
   {
       var lista_temp = cPersonas; //cPersonas - Lista que contiene todo;   
       bool existe = false;      
       CBecaExt cBeca = new cBecaExt();  

       Console.Write("Carnet: ");
       string carnet = Console.ReadLine();

       Cosole.Write("Nombre: ");
       string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

       var index.cPersonas.FindeIndex(x => x.Nombre.Equals(nombre, StringComparison.Ordinal))

       foreach(CAlumno cAlumn in lista_temp)
       {
           if(cAlumn != null && cAlumn.Carnet != null && cAlumn.Carnet.CompareTo(carnet) == 0)
           {
               existe = true;
               Console.Write("Monto: ");
               cBeca.Monto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

               cPersonas.Insert(index,cBeca); // <== ¿cómo hago esto?;
               // agregar ese dato nuevo al registro principal
           }
       }

       if(existe == false)
          Registro_No_Existe();
   }
}
```

¿es posible? son tipos de dato distintos. he intentado clonar la lista para trabajar un copia, intenté crear una lista exclusiva sólo para las becas en el método respectivo de asignación de becas, copiando sólo los datos más relevantes de mi List principal (como carnet y nombre del alumno) pero al momento de recorrer esta "copia", simplemente salta hasta mi condicional en caso de no encontrar registro existente.

Answer (score 0):

no se si esto te servirá el ejemplo que monto es una lista de objetos anónimos lo cual te permite realizar combinaciones de objetos puedes hacerlo de esta forma `new { cpersonita, cbecaExt }` [info obj anonimo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) lo que creo es una lista de objetos anónimos que e voy pasando

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var cpersonita = new Alumno();
        cpersonita.nombre = "fausti";
        cpersonita.carnet = "123456789A";
        var cbecaExt = new CBecaExt();
        cbecaExt.monto= 123;
        var combicompleta = new List<object>().Select(t => new { cpersonita, cbecaExt }).ToList();  
        combicompleta.Add(new {cpersonita,cbecaExt});

    }
     public class CPersona
    {

         public string nombre { get; set; }

    }

    public class Alumno : CPersona
    {
        public string carnet { get; set; }

    }
    public class CBecaExt : Alumno
    {
        public int monto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: interesante, dejo testeo a ver que sale :)

Answer (score 0):

veo que cPersonas es una lista fuertemente tipada List() con lo que sólo podrá albergar datos de tipo CPersona.
Luego veo que CBecaExt hereda de  Alumno pero tú trabajas con registros Alumno. Yo lo haría así si quieres una clase para gestionar Becas pues la creas sin herencia.

```
public class CBecaExt
{
   private int monto;
}
```

Luego en la clase Alumno, creas un miembro que sea Beca.

```
public class Alumno : CPersona
{
   private string carnet;
   // demas atrib;

   public CBecaExt Beca;
}
```

El resto es fácil, sería algo así:

```
public class CFacultad
{
   public void Insertar_Alumno()
   // ...
   public void Solicitar_BecaExt()
   {
      var lista_temp = cPersonas; //cPersonas - Lista que contiene todo;        
      CBecaExt cBeca = new cBecaExt();  

      Console.Write("Carnet: ");
      string carnet = Console.ReadLine();

      Cosole.Write("Nombre: ");
      string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

      var index.cPersonas.FindeIndex(x => x.Nombre.Equals(nombre, StringComparison.Ordinal))

      foreach(CAlumno cAlumn in lista_temp)
      {
          if(cAlumn != null && cAlumn.Carnet != null && cAlumn.Carnet.CompareTo(carnet) == 0)
          {
              Console.Write("Monto: ");
              cBeca.Monto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           
              // Actualizamos el registro ya con la beca y salimos
              cPersonas[index].Beca = cBeca;

              return;
          }
      }
      Registro_No_Existe();
  }
}
```

*** NUEVA PROPUESTA ***

Si es condición insalvable que todo tenga que ser con herencia yo haría así:

```
public class CBecaExt
{
   public int Monto;
}
public class CPersona : CBecaExt
{
   private string nombre;
   // demas atributos
   Nombre() { get { return nombre; } set { nombre = value; } }
   // tpdas mis clases tiene sus propiedades get; set;
}

public class Alumno : CPersona
{
   private string carnet;
   // demas atrib;
}
```

Ya tenemos la jerarquía de herencias de tal forma que Alumno hereda de CPersona que a su vez hereda de CBecaExt. Nuestra función Solicitar_BecaExt() quedaría así:

```
public void Solicitar_BecaExt()
{
   var lista_temp = cPersonas; //cPersonas - Lista que contiene todo;        

   Console.Write("Carnet: ");
   string carnet = Console.ReadLine();

   Cosole.Write("Nombre: ");
   string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

   var index.cPersonas.FindeIndex(x => x.Nombre.Equals(nombre, StringComparison.Ordinal))

   foreach(CAlumno cAlumn in lista_temp)
   {
       if(cAlumn != null && cAlumn.Carnet != null && cAlumn.Carnet.CompareTo(carnet) == 0)
       {
           Console.Write("Monto: ");

           // Actualizamos el registro ya con la beca y salimos
           cPersonas[index].Monto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

           return;
       }
    }
    Registro_No_Existe();
  }
```

Comment: que más quisiera yo dude, trabajar sin herencia en CBecaExt pero estoy obligado, me dieron la jerarquía de clases a seguir.

Comment: He extendido la respuesta a ver si te vale.

Answer (score 0):

Técnicamente no puedes, pero como todo tiene sus excepciones. Imagina que tengo la interfaz IPerson y dos clases que implementan ficha interfaz:

```
public class Father : IPerson
{}

public class Son : IPerson
{}
```

En una tercera clase tengo el siguiente método:

```
public class Programa
{
    static Main(string[] argd)
    {
        List<IPerson> lista = new Lista<IPerson>();

        IPerson Father = new Father();
        lista.Add(father);

        IPerson son = new Son();
        lista.Add(son);
    }
}
```

Father y Son no son el mismo tipo de objeto, pero al heredar de la misma interfaz puede existir en la misma lista.